SQL server trigger not expected behaviour
In this table (T_INVOICES) I have one or more rows for an invoice. This data are used to build the xml file of the Italian invoice. Sometimes an invoice could have two ore more rows with the same description (field 2.2.1.4 - this is the xml name of the field, so it is not up to me). In this case I have to merge the rows. So, for example, from this:
Rows to be merged
I have to create two items like this:
Rows merged correctly
Because of this marging is done manually, I'm trying to do it throgh a trigger. This trigger, posted above, works fine when the rows are inserted using 4 sql statements from SSMS. But It fails if I insert these rows using the web service that is used by SAP (the countability system that holds the data about the invoices). In this second case, it is like if the trigger does not found the row to update, because the output is:
rows merged without update
As you can see, it creates one row from three, but this row has 1000 as amount, not 3000. I hope that I'm clear now. Can someone help me? Maybe is there a way to force the trigger statement execution order (because, in my opinion, the only explanation is that in this second case it runs delete statement and then update one...) Thanks

Wow your column names are awful. What is the table definition, what are the primary keys? What exactly is this trigger supposed to do? Is t_invoices and DOCSADM.T_INVOICES the same table? Please translate into English as this is an English-only site.

That trigger will fail as soon as 0 or 2 or more rows are inserted.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you write by service, I suppose in your transaction you persist 3 rows, so your trigger must works with system table inserted

When you write a trigger, if you want to manage insert / update / delete for more rows, you must use two system tables used by trigger statement:

INSERTED
DELETED

This two tables are very useful. In the first (INSERTED) you have all rows added and all rows updated in your transaction; in the second (DELETED) you have all rows deleted and all rows updated (with old values) in your transaction.
You can use these tables in the statements, using JOIN and so on.
In this way you can manage multi operations in the same transaction.
In your cases, when you insert a statement by MSSSQL you create two differente transaction, because by default every DML operation has been commited with implicit commit.
When you write on your database by service, you have a transaction (normally you annoted your method with @Transactional or other similar annotation) so you must use these tables.
